# Play framework specs2 weird matcher syntax

Tags: scala, specs2

In Play framework specs2 testing I have these lines...

```
    new WithApplication {
      val homeResponse = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
      val resultType = contentType(homeResponse)
      resultType.must( beSome.which( _ == "text/html") )
    }
```

^ This works, but when I pull " beSome.which( _ == "text/html") " into a separate variable...

```
    new WithApplication {
      val homeResponse = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
      val resultType = contentType(homeResponse)
      val textTypeMatcher = beSome.which( _ == "text/html")
      resultType.must( textTypeMatcher )
    }
```

^ Type Mismatch.

expected: Matcher[Option[String]], actual: OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[Option, Nothing, Nothing] ^

What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe it infers the type of `_` based on `resultType`. How about: `val textTypeMatcher = beSome[String].which( _ == "text/html")`?

Comment: you don't need the `.which(_ == "text/html")` part, `beSome("text/html")` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, it infers the type based on `resultType.must(`, because resultType is a `String`. But when you split it, there's nothing to infer from, so you'll get:

```
val textTypeMatcher = beSome.which( _ == "text/html")
=> OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[Option, Nothing, Nothing]
```

But if you add in the type: `beSome[String]`, it you'll get the correct type again.

```
val textTypeMatcher = beSome[String].which( _ == "text/html")
=> OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[Option, String, String]
```

---

Edit:

You can also do this:

```
val textTypeMatcher: OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[Option, String, String] = beSome.which( _ == "text/html")
```

So basically, if you give the type inferrer something to work with, it will infer that `_` must be a string. Otherwise, there is no way for Scala to know that `_` is supposed to be a string.

Comment: Oh, I see. Because the user could be specifying that they want to compare any generic type - int, float, you name it, to string. So you could also do: "val textTypeMatcher = beSome.which( docType: String => docType == "text/html")